# && evaluation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

As far as I know, The logical `&&` works like the following

```
var test = false;
var foo = test && 42;
```

This code, will assign `42` to `foo` **only** if the first condition gets evaluated to `true`. So in this example, `foo` will keep its current value.

I'm wondering why this snippet doesn't work at all:

```
var test = "";
var foo = test && 42;
```

Now, `foo` gets the value from `test` assigned. I'm very confused. The *empty string* is one of Javascripts *falsy values*, so why would the `&&` operator fail in this scenario ?

Can someone help me out with the spec on this one please ?

Comment: ?So in this example, foo will keep its current value." No, it will become `false`

Comment: Answer is in you question,   `"" == false `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have answered your question yourself.

```
var foo = test && 42;
```

`42` will be assigned to `foo` **only if `test` evaluated to true**.

So if `test` is empty string (evaluated to false), 42 won't assigned to `foo`, `foo` will be the empty string.

Answer (score 7):

You're misunderstanding the operator.
`foo = x && y` will *always* assign `foo`.

The `&&` operator evaluates to its left-most "falsy" operand.

`false && 42` evaluates to false; `"" && 42` evaluates to `""`.

`var foo = test && 42;` assigns `false` to `foo`.

Comment: @Yoshi, no, false.  `foo = test && 42` will only assign false to foo if test is false, if test is _falsy_ then the _value_ of test will be assigned to foo, otherwise, 42 will be assigned.