# what is date && new Date(date) doing?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I ran across this in the `bootstrap-datepicker.js` file.

In the `_setDate` function the author does

```
this.viewDate = date && new Date(date)
```

They also do it a couple other times.  What is this doing and why can't they just set

```
this.viewDate = date
```

or

```
this.viewDate = new Date(date)
```

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: @karthikr: No, that's not [how logical operators work in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: Maybe this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162443/218196. Or any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%26%26%22

Answer (score 3):

If `date` value is falsy (in this case, `null` or `undefined` most probably; `''` (empty string), `0` (a number), `NaN` and `false` itself also fit), it is assigned to `this.viewDate` - and `new Date` part won't even be evaluated. Otherwise `new Date(date)` is assigned to `this.viewDate`.

This is roughly equivalent to...

```
this.viewDate = date ? new Date(date) : date;
```

... or, even more verbose:

```
if (date) {
  this.viewDate = new Date(date);
}
else {
  this.viewDate = date;
}
```